# Script works on its own but not as a subroutine of a bigger program

Tags: vbscript

I have written the following code, tested it, and it works.  I then literally copied and pasted it into a larger program as a sub.  I'm getting a Type mismatch on the Split Function now.  I copied & pasted it out of the subroutine and into a new file and it works again.  Any help on why this is happening would be appreciated.

```
Dim oFSO
Dim oNew
Dim oExcel
Dim Folder2
Dim oFile
Dim File, Line
Dim f, fc
Dim x, y, e, i, j 
Dim objSheet, TFile, TSheet
Dim TextLine


'Calls Excel into session and leaves it running in the background
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

'Opens the selected excel file and then lets the user choose the folder to be updated to it

Set oNew = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(BrowseForFolder("Select Excel File to Update"))  
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Folder2 = BrowseForFolder("Choose file containing updated CSV's")
Set f = oFSO.GetFolder(Folder2)
Set fc = f.Files
oNew.Activate

'This loops through every file in the folder, compares the name of the file to the names
'of the sheets in the excel file and overwrites the data to on the spreadsheet
For Each oFile In fc
    TFile = Left(oFile.Name,InStr(oFile.Name,"-")-1)
    For i =1 To oNew.Sheets.Count
        j = InStr(oNew.Sheets(i).Name,"-")-1
        TSheet = Left(oNew.Sheets(i).Name,j)
        if  TSheet = TFile Then
            oNew.Sheets(i).Activate
            set objSheet = oNew.ActiveSheet
            objSheet.Name = Left(oFile.Name,InStr(oFile.Name,".")-1)
            Set File = oFSO.OpenTextFile(oFile)
            x = 1

            Do While File.AtEndofStream <> True
                Line = File.Readline
                TextLine = Split(Line,",")
                y = 1
                For Each e In TextLine
                    objSheet.Cells(x, y) = e
                    y = y+1
                Next
                x=x+1
            Loop
        End If
    Next
Next        

MsgBox "Spreadsheet Updated! New spreadsheet is located in Documents"

' Save merged result as an Excel file in Documents

oNew.SaveAs "SAPDASHBOARD", 51
oNew.Close

' Shut down Excel
oExcel.Quit

Set oExcel = Nothing
Set oNew = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing

Function BrowseForFolder(title)
Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim file : Set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, title, &H4000,0)
If file is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo "No Folder Selected"
    WScript.Quit
End IF
BrowseForFolder = file.self.Path
End Function
```

Comment: for debug purpose can you add 'MsgBox(Line)' before line 'TextLine = Split(Line,",")'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out.  The problem wasn't this portion of the script, it was the fact that one of the other subroutines in the big program was named Split.  So when it tried to run the builtin function "Split" it tried to call the subroutine.  That's a mistake I won't be making again